# Value of type 'some View' has no member 'onDelete' in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, list, swiftui-list, swiftui

in my app I have an `ItemsListView`
It displays the list of items fetched from Core Data.

I can't perform .onDelete on the List. Getting `Value of type 'some View' has no member 'onDelete'`error. And the second error - `Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'View' because only concrete types can conform to protocols` on the List.

```
struct ItemsListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Item>
    var items: FetchedResults<Item>{fetchRequest.wrappedValue}

    init() {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Item>(entity: Item.entity(), sortDescriptors: [])
    }

    var body: some View {
        List { //error 2 appears here
            ForEach(items) { (item : Item)  in
                Text("\(item.name ?? "Nothing")")
            }.onDelete(perform: delete) // getting error here
        }
    }

    func delete(at offset: IndexSet) {
        // delete code will be added here
    }
}
```

Can't figure out how to fix the errors and perform .onDelete

Core Data Item looks like this:

```
public class Item: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
       @NSManaged public var name: String?
       @NSManaged public var recordID: String?
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I see no issues.

Answer (score 2):

Seemed like it was a bug in Xcode or SwiftUI environment. 
After several hours of attempting to fix the issue, I recreated NSManagedObject, cleaned Xcode, Restarted my mac and suddenly it worked.

Comment: If you have this issue again, I've found that clearing the simulator data after modifying NSManagedObject helps: xcrun simctl --set previews delete all (run this in terminal)